# What is "invalid argument" by a rootkit check?

Tags: debian, chkrootkit

I thought I should run a rootkit in connection to [the recent Debian `apt` vulnerability](https://www.debian.org/security/2019/dsa-4371), which I think I have fixed though. I used `chkrootkit` and get these two lines, which I'm not sure what to do with:

```
Checking `lkm'...                                           find: ‘/proc/7952/task/7952/net’: Invalid argument
find: ‘/proc/7952/net’: Invalid argument
```

They stand out in the otherwise clean listing.

Comment: Are those the _full_ error messages from GNU `find`? The `findutils` source code shows no instance of that format being used.  It's always `Invalid argument ... to -size` etc. I.e., it mentions which option received the invalid argument.  Also GNU `find` tends to use a backtick for the opening quote: ` `somename' `

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't even know if `find` is applied here. There's a number of different tests `chkrootkit` performs and these lines are included in the output. That's all I know.